# Unable to get position of target in ScrollLeft or ScrollTo in ASP.NET JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, scroll, horizontal-scrolling

I am trying to scroll horizontal `<div>` by clicking on button and jumping to the position of given element.

I am trying like this:

```
<input type="button" class="hor" onmousedown="scrollDiv6('MyDiv3', Eve_25)" value=@Model.CalendarDates[i].Date />
```

```
var timer6;
function scrollDiv6(divId6, depl6) {
  var scroll_container6 = document.getElementById(divId6);
  var target = $(document.getElementById(depl6)).position().left;

  scroll_container6.scrollTo(target);
  //timer6 = setTimeout('scrollDiv6("' + divId6 + '", ' + depl6 + ')', 1);
}
```

```
<div class="scrolling-wrapper-flexbox scroller"  id="MyDiv3" style="width:100%;position:relative; z-index:2;">
  @for (int i = 0; i < Model.HomeEventsList.Count(); i++) {
    <div class="card2" style="width:300px;height:400px;" id="Eve_@i">
      <div style="text-align:center;">
        <h4 style="font-size:30px;text-align:center;" class="center-fit">@Model.HomeEventsList[i].EventName.ToString()</h4>
        <div class="featuredImageBox" style="width:280px">
          <img height="200" width="280" style="object-fit:cover" src="~/UserFiles/@Model.Owner/min/@Model.HomeEventsList[i].EventFeaturedImage" />
        </div>
        <div style="text-align:center;">
          <span class="center-fit" style="text-align:center;font-size:30px;">
            @Model.HomeEventsList[i].EventStart.DayOfWeek.ToString()
            @Model.HomeEventsList[i].EventStart.ToString("dd MM yyyy")
          </span>
        </div>
        <div style="text-align:center">
          <span class="center-fit" style="text-align:center;font-size:30px;">
            @Model.HomeEventsList[i].EventStart.ToString("HH:mm")
            @Model.HomeEventsList[i].EventDuration
          </span>
        </div>
        <h4 class="center-fit" style="text-align:center;font-size:30px;overflow-wrap: break-word;word-wrap: break-word;hyphens: auto;">@Model.HomeEventsList[i].EventDescription.ToString()</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
  }
</div>
```

On button click nothing happens.

How can I scroll to given element on button click?

Comment: Could try this change from `scrollTo()` to this: `scroll_container6.scrollLeft = 10;` so it scrolls that container 10px to the left.

Comment: When I set scrollLeft value in pixel it works, I cannot scroll to element's position .I think I pass element's I'd wrong way and function does not get executed

Comment: have you tried just using bookmarks?

Comment: Yes,cbut apart from horizontal scroll I also get unexpected vertical scroll as two horizontal lists are not at same y position

Comment: If I could use bookmarks with X position only I would be more than happy